# Why pandas value_counts() generates tuples as index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ["Q1", "Q2", "Q1", "P1"]})
```

That is:

```
    a
 0  Q1
 1  Q2
 2  Q1
 3  P1
```

When I count the values with `counts = df.value_counts(normalize=True)`, indexes change to tuple. That is, `counts.index` is now:

```
MultiIndex([('Q1',),
            ('P1',),
            ('Q2',)],
            names=['a'])
```

but I want preserve the strings as indexes. In other words, I want `counts.index` to be an Index object instead of a MultiIndex.

So, my questions are:

- Why `value_counts` return a MultiIndex?
- Is there an alternative or a "fix" to that?

Comment: It makes sense for `value_counts` to return a MultiIndex, dataframes have more than 1 column more often than not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a MultiIndex because you're starting from a DataFrame, not a Series.

This is actually not very well described in the [`DataFrame.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) documentation:

> The returned Series will have a MultiIndex with one level per input column but an Index (non-multi) for a single label.

What this actually means, is that unless you explicitly pass a single name to `subset`, this will create a MultiIndex. If you use `subset`, make sure to not wrap the name in a list (`df.value_counts(subset=['a'], normalize=True)` would still produce a MultiIndex).

###### workaround

If you don't want a MultiIndex, first slice the column or use the `subset` parameter:

```
counts = df['a'].value_counts(normalize=True)

# or
counts = df.value_counts('a', normalize=True)

counts.index
# Index(['Q1', 'Q2', 'P1'], dtype='object', name='a')
```

Or [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) to automatically convert a single column DataFrame to Series:

```
counts = df.squeeze().value_counts(normalize=True)

counts.index
# Index(['Q1', 'Q2', 'P1'], dtype='object', name='a')
```